# Bootstrap theme and asp.net button events

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a wrap bootstrap theme in an asp.net web forms project and none of my buttons will fire. I found a couple of answers on google but none of them work. Is there any workaround for this? I tried adding UseSubmitBehavior="False" and ValidateRequestMode="Disabled" to my buttons but still not firing.. This seems like a huge problem, I really dont want to make all my buttons ajax calls.

Comment: Have you tried the F12 developer tools to see if there is a scripting error that is preventing the postback operation from firing properly? Are these asp:button's or html buttons with the runat="server" on them? Try setting CausesValidation="false" on the buttons.

Comment: there are no errors and I tried setting that property as well. Pretty frustrating issue... I even tried just throwing a button in the middle of a page and having it write a string to the UI and it doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace that html button with asp.net server control button inheriting all the css.
This may solve your problem.

Comment: I did replace the button with an asp button and the events don't fire. Apparently bootstrap must highjack button clicks for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue.... I had to rebuild the page section by section until I found what was causing it.... Basically it had a div wrapping the entire site and had an id="sb-site" set on it which after searching the entire solution had some js attached to it that wrapped EVERY child control with sb-site and that was stopping the postback...

That was not fun.... :)

// Site Container

if (!$('#sb-site').length) $('body').children().wrapAll(''); // Check if content is wrapped with sb-site, wrap if it isn't.

var $site = $('#sb-site'); // Cache the selector.

if (!$site.parent().is('body')) $site.appendTo('body'); // Check its location and move if necessary.